# What percentage of SQS messages are delivered at least once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, fifo

I understand that standard SQS uses "at least once" delivery, while FIFO messages are delivered exactly once.

**What percentage (roughly) of SQS messages will be duplicated?** This seems like an important factor when weighing standard queues vs FIFO. I wonder if it depends on message throughput?

Comment: Somewhere between 0 and 100%. In practice probably around 1%, but there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon does not provide any detailed number (even a ballpark one) to your question.

The best I can find is in the [AWS SQS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues-at-least-once-delivery.html). Emphasis mine:

> Amazon SQS stores copies of your messages on multiple servers for redundancy and high availability. **On rare occasions**, one of the servers that stores a copy of a message might be unavailable when you receive or delete a message.
>
> If this occurs, the copy of the message isn't deleted on that unavailable server, and you might get that message copy again when you receive messages. Design your applications to be idempotent (they should not be affected adversely when processing the same message more than once).

Based on Amazon's explanation, it's irrelevant to your message throughput. You should consider it as an "expected" AWS platform glitch.

It will not be an issue as long as your message handler is idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

The SQS documentation says that duplicated message can occur if one of the nodes hosting SQS goes down, and cannot receive the delete message.

So based on that, you would have a fairly low number of duplicated messages.  If your application cannot tolerate duplicated messages, then you probably want to use a FIFO queue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question you should be asking is "Is my process idempotent to handle duplicate messages?"

If not, make your process idempotent and use standard SQS queue.

If yes, use standard SQS queue.

You can always use SQS FIFO queue but that will make your application code "incompatible" with other queue systems that do not support such functionality.

Comment: This is a good answer, but not for the question I'm actually asking.